# How to structure time series for binary classification in Keras?

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I'm trying to classify churn (1 or 0) for a user based on day-to-day time series and activity levels, something like this:

```
User     Date      Activity Churn
1    09-01-2018       35      0
1    09-02-2018       17      0
2    09-01-2018        0      1
2    09-02-2018       13      1
etc...
```

Could someone give a few pointers on how this would be setup in Keras to predict the churn value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to treat the date as a cyclical feature to capture patterns in the time stamp.

http://blog.davidkaleko.com/feature-engineering-cyclical-features.html

Keras + SK learn work nicely together. here's an example in my GitHub to extract patterns from the time stamp (just adjust to your needs and replace my Decision Tree with Keras code).

https://github.com/FrancoSwiss/Fraud_Detection/blob/master/Kaggle%20Fraud%20(1).ipynb[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzaHo.png)